# Alternative to debugfs for Android environment

Tags: android, timestamps, alternatives, debugfs

For the purposes of retrieving a file's creation time (if available), I'd use `debugfs`. Unfortunately, `debugfs` is not part of most Android distributions. Are there any similar, more ubiquitous alternatives to `debugfs` that might be present on the typical Android device?

Comment: Use a static binary or use `statx` if kernel version is 4.11+.